# Array and "warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument [-Wformat=]"

Tags: c, arrays, string-formatting

I've been making this program for a project in school, but can't run it properly because of:

> warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument [-Wformat=]

Note: we barely just started learning arrays so please bear with me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf
    int ctr,select,car_in,car_type;
    int a,d,e;
    double t_in[100];
    int car[100],fee=30;
    char plate[100];
int main(){
    a=0;
    d=0;
    e=0;
    start:
p("     A program that will store parking details into array until exit\n\n");
  for(ctr=0;ctr<=14;ctr++)                                     {/*St_Max car loop*/
    p("\t\t  [1] Enter Vehicle  [2] Exit Vehicle\n\n");{
    p("\n\n\n\t\t\t\tChoose: ");
     s("%d",&select);
    if(select==2)
        {goto exit;}
    else if(select==1)
        {goto enter;}
    else{p("ERROR!!");
        system("cls");
        return main();}}
enter:                                               /*St_Park*/
    system("cls");
    p("\n\t     [1] Car 30 [2] SUV 35 [3] Van 40 [4] Motorcycle 25\n\n");
    p("\t   -------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    p("Receipt number: %d",a);
    p("\n\nVehicle Type: ");
     s("%d",&car_type);
    p("\nPlate number: ");
     s("%s",&plate[d]);
    p("\nTime in(24h): ");
     s("%lf",&t_in[e]);
     a++;
     d++;
     e++;
switch (car_type){                                  /*Parking fee range*/
    case 1:
        p("\nParking Fee: %3.2d",fee);
        break;
    case 2:
        p("\nParking Fee: %3.2d",fee+=5);
        break;
    case 3:
        p("\nParking Fee: %3.2d",fee+=10);
        break;
    case 4:
        p("\nParking Fee: %3.2d",fee-=5);
        break;
    default:
        p("\n\n\t\t\t\tERROR !!");
        a--;}
    getch();
    system("cls");
  goto start;                /*Return main*/
exit:                                           /*Release vehicle*/
    system("cls");
    p("\n\n\n\t\tReciept number: ");
     s("%d",&car_in);p("\n\t\t-------------------------------\n");
     e=d=car_in;
    p("\n  Plate number: %s",plate[d]);
    p("\n\n  Time in: %lf",t_in[e]);
    p("\n\n  Parking Fee: %d",fee);
    getch();
    system("cls");
    return main();              }/*Ed_Max car loop*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also: this is a program that inputs/stores car parking details(ie: time, plate, car type and the fee). and also releases them

Comment: This is not a good use of goto.

Comment: @John ive read some blogs warning about goto function. but for now i only know the goto function so for now ill stick to it and learn others as i go ^^

Comment: `return main();` why is your main recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 p("\n  Plate number: %s",plate[d]);
```

Argument that you pass in this statement causes problem. Use a `%c` specifier-

```
p("\n  Plate number: %c",plate[d]);
```

### EDIT

You asked to read a string from `stdin` you should use `fgets`-

```
fgets(plate,sizeof plate,stdin);
```

This will read complete string .

Comment: @CoolGuy  My bad  and thanks for correcting me :). `scanf` didn't had any problem. Corrected my answer.

Comment: @immibis  But the address of `plate[d]` was passed in `scanf` thus it was of type `char *`. statement was -`s("%s",&plate[d]);`.

Comment: @immibis  Not a problem Sir !! :)

Comment: @ameyCU %c can only store one char. i need something that can strore something like EWG-1643.

Comment: @S.Lordan  Then why you need to store char wise . Directly read a  string for stdin.

Comment: @ameyCU sorry but i dont understand what you meant. can you show it to me in code? or link it how to?

Comment: Note: Better to use `fgets(plate, sizeof plate,stdin);`  `fgets()` accounts for the null character so pass 100 rather than 99.

Comment: can i use it multiple times like in an array?

Comment: @S.Lordan  Well yes you can but you don't need to it read whole string at once.